# Save navigation fragment state and restore it back

Tags: android, fragment

> **How to save the navigation fragment State , Positions and restore it back....**

By Switching one to another it cant save its Position
How to Fix This PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: please show us your research and work till now

Comment: [link]http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/           This is the code i am using with webview